# Selenium IDE autocomplete

Tags: drop-down-menu, autocomplete, selenium-ide

I am new in Selenium IDE and I have a problem.
I need to record next "while filled 1st dropdown field 2 other auto-filled themselves".
I've tried to do that in many different ways but nothing works.
Commands which I used to made selection from 1st field:

```
SendKeys
Pause
AssertText
MouseOver
ClickAt
```

I will appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get value from the dropdown use **select** Method and you don't need to use pause.

```
string select(string $selectLocator, string $optionLocator)
```

> Select an option from a drop-down using an option locator.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to store your by default 1st dropdown field using

```
storeSelectedLabel  |  //select  |  defaultVal
```

Then you have to store second field in variable

```
storeText  |  secondDropdownFieldTarget  |  secondField
```

And now check by using

```
gotoIf  |  storedVars['defaultVal']!=storedVars['secondField']  |  successLabel
label   |  successLabel
select  |  secondFieldTarget
```